# How do I execute child ps1's when calling the parent ps1 from .NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, powershell, azure

I have an ASP.NET application that I am wishing to call a Powershell Script to get results. I've done some digging and come up with a lot of very dated information relating to PS1/2 but nothing for PS4 upwards.

I have a PowerShell script that presently completes some operations and outputs an ArrayList to the PowerShell console. The Powershell Script calls another PowerShell script:

```bsh
.\Get-AzureSubscription.ps1

$environments = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$resourceGroups = Get-AzureRMResourceGroup

foreach($thisResourceGroup in $resourceGroups)
{
    $resourceGroupVMs = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $thisResourceGroup.ResourceGroupName

    $environment = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
    $environment | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ResourceGroupName -Value $thisResourceGroup.ResourceGroupName
    $environment | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Id -Value $thisResourceGroup.ResourceId

    $machines = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

    foreach($thisMachine in $resourceGroupVMs)
    {
        $machine = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
        $machine | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name Name -value $thisMachine.Name
        $machine | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name ResourceGroupName -value $thisResourceGroup.ResourceGroupName 

        $status = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $thisResourceGroup.ResourceGroupName -Name $thisMachine.Name -Status | `
                         Select-Object -ExpandProperty Statuses | `
                         Where-Object { $_.Code.StartsWith("PowerState") } | `
                         Select-Object -ExpandProperty Code

        $regex = [Regex] '\/(.*?)$'
        $machine | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name Status -value $regex.Match($status).Groups[1].Value


        $machines.Add($machine) > $null;
    }

    $environmentStatuses = $machines | Select-Object ResourceGroupName -ExpandProperty Status | Group-Object ResourceGroupName, Status

    $environment | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name Statuses -value $environmentStatuses
    $environments.Add($environment) > $null;
}

$environments
```

I also have the following .NET code that attempts to execute the outer script by having the content of the PS1 script passed in as a string:

```cs
public Collection<PSObject> RunScript(string script, Dictionary<string, string> parameters = null)
{
    // Validate parameters
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(script)) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(script)); }
    RunspaceConfiguration runspaceConfiguration = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();

    using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(runspaceConfiguration))
    {
        runspace.Open();

        using (RunspaceInvoke invoker = new RunspaceInvoke(runspace))
        {
            invoker.Invoke("Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted");

            Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();

            Command scriptCommand = new Command(script, true);
            parameters?.Select(kvp => new CommandParameter(kvp.Key, kvp.Value))
                .ForEach(scriptCommand.Parameters.Add);

            pipeline.Commands.Add(scriptCommand);

            var result = pipeline.Invoke();

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is that if I call the ps1 from .NET, it fails complaining that `The term '.\Get-AzureSubscription.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.` If I execute the ps1 from PowerShell, it executes without issue.

If I copy and paste the content of the `Get-AzureSubscription.ps1` into the ps1 that is directly called by .NET instead of linking the two scripts, everything is passed back to .NET successfully.

Comment: When you use `PowerShell.Invoke()`, did you inspect value of `PowerShell.Streams.Error` after invocation?

Comment: If I use `PowerShell.Invoke()` there is no error, it skips nicely past that line, but there's nothing returned from PowerShell... my `result` is an empty collection

Comment: It does not answer my question. The fact, that you does not have any exception thrown from `PowerShell.Invoke()` does not mean, that you does not have any error in error stream.

Comment: Ah... I see... I had incorrectly assumed that the lack of an exception would mean there were no errors, but in fact, the same errors show in the stream.`The term '.\Get-AzureAssistantSubscription.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.` and another related to the fact that the ps1 that the outer script is calling isn't run.

Comment: Are you sure that script file placed in current working directory? Try to use full absolute path instead of relative path.

Comment: The script files are both in the Cmdlets folder of my application's bin\Release and the script I call directly from asp.net is being called from that directory.

Comment: Did you change working directory to `bin\Release\Cmdlets` before calling script? How did you execute first script file (from your code its looks like you loading script text and execute it instead of execute script file by name)?

Answer (score 1):

There's no guarantee that the working directory of the .NET application will be the same as the script you invoke from within it.

You can use this trick to figure out the full path to the invoking script (replace the first line with this):

```
$AzureSubscriptionScript = Join-Path $PSScriptRoot "Get-AzureAssistantSubscription.ps1"
& $AzureSubscriptionScript
```

`$PSScriptRoot` is an automatic variable that holds the path of the current/invoking script's location on disk as its value

Comment: This works when I execute the script from PowerShell manually, but when I invoke it from my asp.net project, I get the following exception: `The expression after '&' in a pipeline element produced an object that was not valid. It must result in a command name, a script block, or a CommandInfo object.`

Comment: Are you by any chance referencing an old version of the `System.Management.Automation.dll` assembly in your project?

Comment: v 10.0.10586 from NuGet